# MySQL query combining unique maximum values grouped by time interval

Tags: mysql, grouping

I'm trying to query a table that has many records for many object for many time intervals. What I am trying to do is return the maximum score obtained on that particular day For example on this table

```
ID | obj | score | time 
1,  'a', 2,     DEC 21 2014, 5:00:00
2,  'a', 4,     DEC 21 2014, 8:00:00
3,  'a', 7,     DEC 22 2014, 10:00:00
4,  'a', 6,     DEC 22 2014, 16:00:00
5,  'b', 0,     DEC 21 2014, 4:00:00
6,  'b', 2,     DEC 21 2014, 8:00:00
7,  'b', 4,     DEC 22 2014, 10:00:00
8,  'b', 8,     DEC 22 2014, 18:00:00
```

and the query would return four records

```
DEC 21 2014, a, 4
DEC 21 2014, b, 2
DEC 22 2014, a, 7
DEC 22 2014, b, 8
```

I know distinct command and I've tried different grouping commands, but have not had success yet. Can anyone point in me with the kinds of key words I should be employing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, not tested:

```
SELECT obj, MAX(score)
FROM a_table
WHERE time >= particular_day AND time < (particular_day + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY obj
```

I prefer to use these two conditions over converting to date.

If You want get all days in one query:

```
SELECT obj, MAX(score), CAST(time AS date)
FROM a_table
GROUP BY obj, CAST(time AS date)
```

Comment: if I have data over a four month period, would I have to execute that query 120+ times?

Comment: I've edited answer. In the first case You would have to call it many times. I've interpreted the phrase "that particular day" that You need only one day. The second one will do.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

SELECT DATE(time), obj, MAX(score) FROM tbl GROUP BY 1,2

(What is the Primary Key on the table?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT time, obj, max(score)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY time, obj;
```

This should do exactly what you want.

Comment: The issue is that this is returning multiple records for the same object on the same day. There should only be one record of the object per day

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like this

```
   SELECT * FROM tablename 
    WHERE (time > start_time)
      AND (time < end_time)
```